# Is my understanding of how this C program works correct?

Tags: c, argv, getopt, argc

in the following program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        char *delivery = "";
        int thick = 0;
        int count = 0;
        char ch;

        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                fprintf(stdout, "Argv[%i] = %s\n", i, argv[i]); /* printing to understand (ptu) */
        }
        while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t")) != -1)
                switch (ch) {
                        case 'd':
                                fprintf(stdout, "Optind in case 'd': %i\n", optind);
                                delivery = optarg;
                                break;
                        case 't':
                                fprintf(stdout, "Optind in case 't': %i\n", optind);
                                thick = 1;
                                break;
                        default:
                                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option: '%s'\n", optarg);
                                return 1;
                }
        fprintf(stdout, "Argc: %i\n", argc); /* ptu */
        fprintf(stdout, "Argv: %p\n", argv); /* ptu */
        argc -= optind;
        argv += optind;
        fprintf(stdout, "Optind: %i. Argc after subtraction: %i, Argv after increment: %p\n", optind, argc, argv);
        if (thick)
                fprintf(stdout, "Thick crust!\n");
        if (delivery[0])
                fprintf(stdout, "To be delivered %s\n", delivery);
        fprintf(stdout, "Ingredients:\n");
        for (count = 0; count < argc; count++)
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", argv[count]);
        return 0;
}
```

When I run the above program with arguments shown below I get the following output:

```
[u@h c]$ ./prog -t -d yesterday anchovies goatcheese pepperoni
Argv[0] = ./prog
Argv[1] = -t
Argv[2] = -d
Argv[3] = yesterday
Argv[4] = anchovies
Argv[5] = goatcheese
Argv[6] = pepperoni
Optind in case 't': 2
Optind in case 'd': 4
Argc: 7
Argv: 0x7ffebee8e498
Optind: 4. Argc after subtraction: 3, Argv index: 0x7ffebee8e4b8
Thick crust!
To be delivered yesterday
Ingredients:
anchovies
goatcheese
pepperoni
```

I would like to know if my understanding of what's going on under the hood is accurate, specifically for the argument parsing steps in the program. Apologies for not sharing a more minimal reprex, but in this case I probably couldn't. I wouldn't have spammed stackoverflow if I could show this to a friend who understood C. So, please bear with me. Here goes nothing:

1. Defined main to accept command-line (cl) parameters. This requires two parameters:

   - integer argc which will contain the number of cl parameters including the name of the program, in this case it is 7
   - array of strings (i.e. array of char pointers), each element of which will point to the memory address of the first element of each string literal (stored in the CONSTANT memory block) passed in as a cl parameter to the program.
2. for loop (self explanatory)
3. On each run of the while loop getopt() will parse the argv[] array and assigns the next matching character from the `optstring "d:t"` to character variable `ch`, until it runs out of options (no pun intended) which is when it will return `-1` and the control will exit the while loop.

   - at each such pass `optind` (which is initiated at 1 presumably because argv[0] is the program name) will be incremented to contain the index of the next element to be processed in argv... So in `case 't', optind = <index of "-d" i.e. 2>`, and in `case 'd', optind = <index of "anchovies" i.e. 4>` (this is because `getopt()` realizes from the "`:`" after '`d`' in the `optstring` that `-d` will be followed by its `optarg` on the command line, thus `optind` is incremented to "4" here instead of being "3")
   - after `-t` and `-d yesterday` are processed `getopt()` can't find anything else in `argv[]` which matches elements in the `optstring`; thus it returns `-1` and we break out of the while loop. `optind` remains set to 4 because getopt didn't find anything else after '-d' from the optstring.
4. We now decrement `optind`'s value "4" from `argc` to ensure we skip past the `option arguments` (which we have already parsed) to the remaining three `non-option` arguments. We also increment `argv`—which initially pointed to memory location of `argv[0]` i.e. `"./prog"`—by `<optind * sizeof(char pointer on a 64-bit machine); i.e. 4 * 8>` which is why argv now points 32 bytes ahead in memory: `0x7ffebee8e4b8 - 0x7ffebee8e498 == 0x20`. In other words, argv[0] points to "anchovies"
5. We then print stuff depending on values of `thick`, `delivery` and loop through the remaining non-option arguments to print them as well...

Comment: _I wouldn't have spammed stackoverflow if I could show this to a friend who understood C._   Spamming is never good, even if you apologize in advance. This question is not a good match for StackOverflow.  Try running this with a debugger to get a better understanding of how the program works.

Comment: @jdigital:  I think the question is perfectly acceptable and on-topic.  It is about programming, it asks a specific answerable question ("is this description correct?"), it contains all the information needed to answer the question.  The program included is minimal in that every part of it is related to the question, and really isn't all that long anyhow.

Comment: In the error case, the faulty option is stored in an integer `optopt`, not in the string `optarg`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

I would offer two notes:

- "String literal" refers to a string that is actually defined within your program, as characters between `""` delimiters.  The "CONSTANT block" isn't a standard concept but I suppose you mean a block of read-only memory which is loaded from the binary, since that's where string literals normally reside.  The strings which the `argv` pointers point to are not of this kind; they can't be, because they are not known when the binary is created.  Instead, they are located in some unspecified region of memory, and you may modify them in place if you wish (though this is likely to make your code confusing); e.g. `argv[0][3] = 'x'` would be legal.  (C17 standard 5.1.2.2.1 (2)).
- Some people might likewise find it confusing to modify the values of `argc` and `argv` within `main`, and would suggest that you assign the modified values to some other variables instead:

```
int remaining_argc = argc - optind;
char **remaining_argv = argv + optind;
```

Comment: are the strings that argv pointers point to located in HEAP then?

Comment: @computronium: As I said, it's unspecified; different implementations may do it in different ways.  On my system (Linux) they are placed on the stack, and this is common but not necessarily universal.  But you don't need to know this to write a correct program.